# ASP.NET MVC model variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In a razor page, I'd like assign a javascript variable from a model property (not all the model)

I tried several solution but no one works.

This code is plaed at the end of the razor page. The value I get for

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var method = @Model.MethodName;

        if (!methodd)
            alert(method);
    );

</script>
```

I tried this too :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var mName = '';

        @if(@Model.MethodName != string.Empty)
            mName = @Model.MethodName;

        alert(mName);

    });

</script>
```

In the console I get :

```
var method = ;
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: If this is a string property, you need something like `"@Model.MethodName"`

Comment: @adiga Of course I have this property in the model

Answer (score -1):

A solution would be to use JSON.Encode() method.